# install windows 7 32-bit using boot-camp on snow-leopard

Tags: snow-leopard, macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I have Snow-Leopard running on my MacBook. I want to install Windows 7 32-bit Professional. I have already purchased copy of Windows from Amazon. I never'ed install Windows on my MacBook till date, so I don't know what to do, and how to install it.

Please share your experiences of installing Windows using Boot-Camp.
I need screen-shots or video that can help me with installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thousands of tutorials can be found using Google or YouTube, for example:

http://www.simplehelp.net/2009/01/15/using-boot-camp-to-install-windows-7-on-your-mac-the-complete-walkthrough/

http://gizmodo.com/5387353/how-to-survive-boot-camp-and-run-win-7-on-a-mac

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OM2495dmO0I